# Как читать файл по 128 бит?

Tags: c++

```
while(!feof(f))
   {

    fread(&buf, 128, 1, f);
     SendData(buf,128);

    is++;
   }
```

Так смог получить только первые 128 бит. Как при каждом цикле получать следующие 128 бит?
Как определить конец файла?

Comment: Если нужно именно в битах: `128 бит == 16 байт`

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то, это вы действуете по 128 **байт**.

```
do
{
    if (n = fread(buf,1,128,f)) // Если считано не 0 байт
        SendData(buf,n);
} while(n == 128);  // Или while(!feof(f)); - после неудачного чтения...
```